# Terraform is using wrong google project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp

I deleted the project `projects/project1-301106` and then created a new which ends with `301108`. But terraform always try to use the old project.

```
Error: Error creating Network: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/project1-301106' was not found, notFound
```

I deleted .terraform directory and files, ran `terraform init`. Also cleared gcould and reauth but still the same error.

Comment: You can try deleting it from a state file with [terraform state rm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/rm.html)

Comment: I already deleted the tfstate files.

Comment: Is the project correctly set in the Google Provider? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#configuring-the-provider

Comment: What is the result of this command `gcloud config list`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

Remove these files and folders:

```
sudo rm -r .terraform .terraform.lock.hcl terraform.tfstate terraform.tfstate.backup
```

Then:

```
terraform init
```

Finally:

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this was caused by running `gcloud auth application-default login` which opened in a browser tab using the wrong project. Removing terraform files did not solve this for me.